# Passing float from one view controller to another

Tags: objective-c, ios6, floating-point, xcode4.5, primitive-types

Quite a stupid problem really, but I am very new to the world of programming an have run into this problem where I am trying to pass a float variable from one view controller to another. I have found this great way in which to do it with strings, but I cannot get it to work with floats. Any suggestions?

Your help is much appreciated!

```
//Passing the data in first view controller
float savedAudioLevel = _slAudioVolume.value;
NSUserDefaults *defaultsAudio = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaultsAudio setFloat:savedAudioLevel forKey:@"currentAudioLevel"];
[defaultsAudio synchronize];

//Receiving the data in second
NSUserDefaults *defaultsAudio = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
float loadfloatAudio = [defaultsAudio valueForKey:@"currentAudioLevel"]; //Getting an error here
_currentAudioVolume = loadfloatAudio;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have an easier time if you [embed your "`float`" into a "`NSNumber`" object](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSNumber/numberWithFloat%3a), which is a native Objective C object you can more easily pass around.

["`valueForKey`", at least when called on a "`NSDictionary`" object](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/valueForKey%3a), only works for NSStrings when doing KVC.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Have to find another way then.